# Keyframe navigation for specific action/property

Tags: animation

So I know you can chronologically navigate between all keyframes on a subject using the arrow-and-diamond button. I was wondering if there's a way to specify which property or action to navigate between instead of navigating on every single keyframe visible in the timeline.

For example, if I had keyframes where some are for changing the light's location and some keyframes are for changing the light's power, is there a way I can navigate between the keyframes that are specific to changing the light's power and ignore the keyframes for the light's location? That would make it a lot easier to tell where things are changing for specific properties.

If there is no way to do this, can you suggest a method to manage this type of animation easier? Should I be using the dope sheets or something else instead? I find that the timeline gets too clusters sometimes with the location, rotation, etc changes all bunched up together in one UI.

Comment: i think that's why there are markers...or you write (or search for) an add-on which assist you in your special case